# concatenation of several csv filles using bash

Tags: bash, csv, paste

I am dealing with the concatenation of several multi-lines csv filles (containing equal number of lines and share the first column ) given in the following format:

```
test_1200
lig2: -4.6600
lig5: -6.8100
lig8: -5.1900
lig76: -5.5700
lig88: -5.8500
lig123: -6.0600
lig177: -0.1400
lig331: -8.0000
lig394: -4.3600
lig420: -5.5200
lig550: -4.3200
lig1000: -7.5800
lig1005: -7.5200
lig1011: -8.1500
```

In order to merge several csv filles, the following command is used in my bash script:

```
# merge several csv filles located within same home directory
paste -d'\t' "${home}"/*.csv >> "${home}"/results_ALL.csv
```

The problem of that method that in the resulted file there is a unused tab between the two interphases, where line number is bigger than lig1000 (here is the example for merging of two filles):

```
       test_1200    test_7000
lig2: -4.6600   lig2: -5.7600
lig5: -6.8100   lig5: -5.9100
lig8: -5.1900   lig8: -5.1100
lig76: -5.5700  lig76: -5.0500
lig88: -5.8500  lig88: -4.7200
lig123: -6.0600 lig123: -6.2600
lig177: -0.1400 lig177: -0.7200
lig331: -8.0000 lig331: -9.3700
lig394: -4.3600 lig394: -4.7500
lig420: -5.5200 lig420: -4.4000
lig550: -4.3200 lig550: -4.9200
lig1000: -7.5800    lig1000: -5.3800
lig1005: -7.5200    lig1005: -6.7700
lig1011: -8.1500    lig1011: -6.6000
```

Note that there is a tab (after lig1000) between 3 last lines that I would like to avoid.

Additionally would it be possible to keep only the first column from the first csv file (containing the number of the line, like lig1) and remove the rest (which are the edentical), yet preserving the index of the CSV in the resulted fussed file (test_xxx)?

Comment: I thought CSV files were strictly comma-separated value files?

Comment: to get rid of the common first column consider using `join`; to convert from a delimited file format to a fixed width format file it gets a little more interesting as it will depend on the number of files you're joining and the widest field in each column; if @jared_mamrot's `column` answer doesn't work then consider updating the question with more details/example data

Comment: could you post the method using join as the answer in order that I could check it ?

Comment: There is no extra tab. There is just _one_ tab between the columns on _all_ lines. It's just that you are looking at the file with an editor that uses tabs every 4 columns. If you change it to the normal 8-column tab view, it will line up correctly.

Comment: sorry I just looked at it as the regular txt file and did not notice it. so in exel csv should be like normal 4 column csv (donot have it on my mac ight now)?